# Перебор массива вложенного в массив в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

Парни, помогите разобраться в следующем.
Есть массив

```
var myArr1 = [ 
['a',
    ['a1','a2','a3'] 
], 
    ['b',['b1','b2','b2'] ], 
['c',
    ['c1','c2','c3'] ]
].
```

Из него создаются блоки для каждого элемента с индексом 0 по клику.

```
$(document).on('click','.goods',function(){

    myArr1.forEach(function(item){
        $('#lists').append('<div class="loot">'+item[0]+'</div>');              
    });
});
```

А вот дальше я застрял на таком изврате:
хочу,чтобы по клику на любой блок (например с названием b) - данный список очищался, а создавался следующий, с блоками для b из его массива.

Типа on.click-"b"->append.все блоки, которые есть для b.
Или более графически нужно вот это:

|a| |b| |c| => при клике на кнопку a или b, или c (в данном вопросе 'b') => 
|b1| |b2| |b3|.

Дюже хочется узнать, как такое реализовать можно???
Просто зациклился уже по кругу ходить, в голове одна каша. Нужно свежее мнение со стороны. Поможете?
up =)

Comment: [метод empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) удаляет все вложенные элементы

Comment: не,удалить я могу и через $('#lists').html(''); а вот как сделать создание блоков для всех элементов для выбранного блока - беда бедущая,второй день без сна оставляющая =(((

Comment: А тебе больше ничего и не надо, после удаления, просто добавляешь новые элементы по аналоги с тем, как они сейчас у тебя добавляются

Comment: Не-а, я не могу обратиться к этим массивам. я запутался как прописать индексы именно для нажатой кнопки, а потом в массиве найти массив значений для этой кнопки =/

Comment: И беда в том,что думал сделать ключами, но там овер 800 значений и каждому по 5-50 ключей.

Comment: Мне бы вот на данном примере (ибо именно так я и создал этот кошмар) узнать каким циклом это реализовать.

Comment: Есть у кого какие идеи,а?

Comment: Совсем никого? =(

Comment: не торопись, ты всего час назад вопрос задал

Comment: Это конечно писец,но как вариант я сделал так:
var myArr1 = [['a',['a1','a2','a3']],['b',['b1','b2','b2']],['c',['c1','c2','c3']]];
$(document).on('click','.goods',function(){
    myArr1.forEach(function(item){
        $('#lists').append('<div class="loot" data="'+item[1]+'">'+item[0]+'</div>');              
    });
});
$(document).on('click','.loot',function(){
var a = $(this).attr('data'),b = $(this),a1 = Array.from(a.split(','));
a1.forEach(function(item){$(b).append('<div class="loot_desc">'+item+'</div>');});}); Матом не пинайте ибо я всего месяц как начал с нуля учить ЯП вообще

Comment: Вам в любом случае лучше перейти на объекты, потому что если для текущей задачи - вывести всё-всё списком - массива вам хватает, то начнется изврат, когда потребуется получить описание для какого-либо конкретного элемента вместо простого быстрого доступа по свойству объекта.

Comment: Объекты? В данном примере как их можно было бы применить?

Answer (score 0):

В качестве одного из вариантов, при создании начального списка можно сразу навешивать обработчики на создаваемые элементы, в этом случае доступны сразу их индексы, и поиск делать не нужно.

Например:

```
$(document).on('click','.goods',function(){
    var list = $('#lists').empty(); // по клику очищаем элемент, чтобы не добавлялось одно и то же несколько раз
    myArr1.forEach(function(item,index){
        var element = $('<div class="loot">'+item[0]+'</div>');
        element.click(function(){
            var nestedElements = myArr1[index][1]; // получаем массив для вывода
            $('#lists').empty() // очищаем элемент
                       .append( // добавляем новые элементы
                           nestedElements.map(function(nestedItem){
                               return $('<div class="loot">'+nestedItem+'</div>');
                           })
                       );
        });
        list.append(element);              
    });
});
```

Comment: Огого... Круто! Спасибо.

Comment: Теперь бы ещё понять что тут куда,зачем и почему

Comment: У меня вопрос, а можно ли ключу в объекте качестве значения задавать массив со значениями? И если да, то как эти значения можно перебрать?

Comment: @Olejjon, не понял вопроса

Comment: Ну, можно ли так сделать var obj1 ={ "name":["thurname 1","thurname 2","thurname 3"]} и как потом  их вытягивать,каким методом или циклом?

Comment: Ты просто написал про объекты, а пример не дал для моего случая. Прости, я понимаю,что вопрос тупой,но у меня правда затык. Проблему решить - решил, но чуйство,что можно сделать красиво и более эффективно - не даёт мне покоя...

Comment: @Olejjon, в данном случае это ничем не отличается от массива, который ты сейчас используешь, просто в массиве ключами являются числа, а в данном случае - ключ - `name`. `obj['name']` так же выдаст массив

Comment: @Olejjon, я про объекты не писал :-)